# pandas .unique() TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column that contains "tags" for SQL and I was curious to see what unique values would be for these tags.

For my pandas dataframe column if I use `tags.m_tags.unique()` this will through an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Manually looking at the data `m_tags` it is in list format looks like this:

```
[reheat, cmd]
[discharge, temp, air, sensor]
[flow, air, sensor]
[zone, temp, air, sensor]
```

Would anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) method and chain [`unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) method to it:

```
result=tags['m_tags'].explode().unique()
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output

**EDIT :** If you have dictionary then use:

```
result=df['tags'].apply(lambda x:list(x.values())).explode().unique()
```

Comment: great thanks that worked ill hit the green X when I can

Comment: Would you happen to have a tip for something very similar, a separate column is dictionary "tags" instead of a list type. Ill get an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: I could just make a new question too on SO if preferred

Comment: I will try...please tell how that dict looks like?

Comment: `{'equip_name': 'VMA-1-7', 'equip_type': 'vav'}`

Comment: Updated my answer...Kindly  have a look **:)**